# Display all items of for loop inside string interpolation Vue JS

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, vuejs2, string-interpolation

I'm trying to display all of the return openingHour values from my for loop and show it inside a p tag of my vue page.

I'm not sure if i'm supposed to use a computed property for this as I believe computed properties are only supposed to return one value?

If i were to use a method, how can i display the data inside a string interpolation?

Currently if i were to console.log(openingHour); it will display all the opening hours from all objects. but if i return the openingHour, it will show me only the first data.

```js
import {
  Vue,
  Component
} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {
  namespace
} from 'vuex-class';
import FoodMerchant from '../../models/FoodMerchant';
import {
  DateTime
} from 'luxon';

export default class MerchantProfilePage extends Vue {
  @namespace('merchant').State('foodMerchant') foodMerchant!: FoodMerchant;

  get showOpeningHour() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.foodMerchant.opening_hours.data.length; i++) {
      let openingHour = DateTime.fromObject({
        hour: this.foodMerchant.opening_hours.data[i].startHour,
        minute: this.foodMerchant.opening_hours.data[i].startMinute,
        zone: this.foodMerchant.timezone
      }).toFormat('h:mm a');

      return openingHour;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
// This will display as 9.30 AM
<p>{{showOpeningHour}}</p>
```

[image: Data Object of Opening Hours]

Comment: showOpeningHour() function should return a list of strings or objects, then you bind it to your v-for loop.

Comment: _"I believe computed properties are only supposed to return one value"_  an array is still one value

Answer (score 0):

Given `<p>{{showOpeningHours}}</p>`, the `showOpeningHours` computed property could format the opening hours data into one long string:

```
get showOpeningHours() {
  const daysOfWeek = ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'];
  const openingHours =
    this.foodMerchant.opening_hours.data
      .map(hours => {
        const timeStr = DateTime.fromObject({
                          hour: hours.startHour,
                          minute: hours.startMinute,
                          zone: this.foodMerchant.timeZone
                        }).toFormat('h:mm a');
        return daysOfWeek[hours.day] + ' ' + timeStr;
      });
  return openingHours.join(' / ');
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwvr8o5m6q)

Or you could change the computed property into an array, rendered with [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for):

```
get showOpeningHours() {
  const daysOfWeek = ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'];
  const openingHours =
    this.foodMerchant.opening_hours.data
      .map(hours => {
        const timeStr = DateTime.fromObject({
                          hour: hours.startHour,
                          minute: hours.startMinute,
                          zone: this.foodMerchant.timeZone
                        }).toFormat('h:mm a');
        return daysOfWeek[hours.day] + ' ' + timeStr;
      });
  return openingHours; // <-- RETURNS ARRAY
}
```

*template:*

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="hours in showOpeningHours" key="hours.day">{{hours}}</li>
</ul>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywjm7r5vn1)